# scatter3D() function ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, graph

I am building a 3D graph for a representation.
I used the following code.

```
ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
ax.scatter3D(x_int, y_int, der_int, c=der_int, cmap = 'hsv')
```

I got the above error. `x_int, y_int, der_int` are integer lists.
I need a solution for this.

Comment: Please post the full error and the relevant code the shows how ```x_int``` and ```y_int``` are defined.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you could create minimal working code with example data driectly in code. And then we can run it, see if your data type is correct, test ideas to resolve problem.

Comment: if I use list with integers then I get plot. Error can means that you have list with objects which are not directly integers

Comment: I resolved the error after some time sorry for the inconvenience.